# How to achieve bi-directional data synchronization in Oracle db 19c?

Tags: oracle, synchronization, oracle-sqldeveloper, bidirectional

I have two databases. One is hosted locally and named 'local db' and other is hosted remotely, and is named 'remote'.

I have the same data on both databases. If one table in local db undergoes any changes like a DDL and DML operation, it should affect the other, remote database, and vice versa.

I have achieved uni-directional data synchronization by using triggers, which means I am able to make changes in one table in the local database, and it will be reflected in the remote database.

However, I need bi-directional changes.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_test_order_local
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON test_order_local
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; 
BEGIN
  -- Insert, update, or delete the corresponding row in the remote database
  IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO test_order_remote@test_remote1 (id, desc1, desc2, desc23)
    VALUES (:NEW.id, :NEW.desc1, :NEW.desc2, :NEW.desc23);
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    UPDATE test_order_remote@test_remote1
    SET id = :NEW.id, desc1 = :NEW.desc1, desc2 = :NEW.desc2, desc23 = :NEW.desc23
    WHERE id = :OLD.id AND desc1 = :OLD.desc1 AND desc2 = :OLD.desc2 and desc23 = :OLD.desc23; -- Use the unique columns for the WHERE clause
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    DELETE FROM test_order_remote@test_remote1
    WHERE id = :OLD.id AND desc1 = :OLD.desc1 AND desc2 = :OLD.desc2 and desc23 = :OLD.desc23; -- Use the unique columns for the WHERE clause
  END IF;
  commit;
END;
/
```

This is my trigger code. If I run in the local database, uni-directional data sync is achieved successfully. But the same code with a db name modification done on the remote database is not working... it's throwing the following error (or sometimes the script runs for a very long time):

> error - ORA-12518, TNS:listener could not hand off client connection

I verified as my listener file and TNS are configured same. The Processes and network connection are also good.

How can I resolve this error to achieve bi-direction syncing?

Comment: The only way to do bi-directional syncing is to have a rigorous timestamping of all DML via triggers and metadata columns, ensuring that the clocks on both systems are perfectly in sync and hopefully in the same timezones to avoid some unpleasing conversions, and a very intelligent copy engine that assembles dynamic SQL to replicate changes in either direction. As for DDL, that's much harder. It can be done, but we're talking about many dozens of pages of rather complex code and rules and `dbms_metadata` use to successfully merge structure like that. Not for the faint of heart.

Comment: As for using triggers to do the syncing, how are you going to prevent a self deadlock? If you update the remote, the remote trigger will try to update the local, which is what initiated the change. I don't think this is a workable strategy for bi-directional syncing.

Comment: What is the actual business problem you need to solve?  Bidirectional replication is possible but 1) that's a DBA infrastructure problem, 2) that's a whole lot of infrastructure and installation steps, and 3) that doesn't normally replicate DDL.  There are certainly situations where it makes sense to invest all the time and effort required to make bidirectional replication work.  But in the vast majority of cases, you'd want to choose a different solution to whatever problem you have.

Comment: Also note that your current trigger doesn't actually keep the tables in sync.  If you delete a row locally, for example, but rollback the transaction, the remote change won't rollback and the tables will be out of sync

Comment: As noted, this problem is not for the faint of heart. Because of the complexity of the task, this sort of thing is usually handled by a commercial-grade purpose-built tool like Oracle GoldenGate. Build-your-own solutions are rare.

Comment: If both databases are in use, then insert of the same keys with different data into the same table in nearly the same moment will break this bidirectional hell of triggers